# Hide browser page content on Android when overview button is clicked

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

[hide page content on overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/347IY.png)

I want to hide the content of the page when the browser app it is not in the foreground. In other words, when the user presses the overview button.
I've tried onblur, blur, visibilitychange and focusout() without success. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried $(window).focus() and $(window).blur()?

Comment: Hello Eric. Yes, Please try this jsbin [link](https://jsbin.com/sehahir/) in android browser app.